# How to make QFileDialog not modal in Qt5?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qfiledialog, non-modal

In previous versions of Qt we were able to use following constructor of file dialog:

```
QFileDialog(QWidget * parent = 0, const char * name = 0, bool modal = FALSE)
```

So, it looks like it was possible to make non-modal file dialog. But now (in Qt5) we haven't such parameters in constructor. Also QFileDialog ignores `setWindowModality(Qt::NonModal);` and `setModal(false);` (I've checked, that if `windowModality() == Qt::NonModal && isModal() == false`, file dialog window is still modal).

**Do you have ideas, how to make my file dialog non-modal?**

Details: my file dialog inherited from QFileDialog. It works absolutely as expected. The only thing I need is to make it non-modal, but I can't find solution on SO and on qt-project. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you open the QFileDialog?

Comment: I use `QFileDialog::open()` to open my file dialog.

Comment: According to the docs, "QDialog::open() Shows the dialog as a **window modal** dialog...". Try `QDialog::show()` instead.

Comment: @KubaOber, it is from Qt documentation (see: http://doc.qt.digia.com/3.2/qfiledialog.html )

Comment: @Ilya What I meant was that you've merely reproduced a documentation bug. It should have read `bool modal = false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "problem" is that you open the file dialog as a modal window by calling `QDialog::open()` function. According to the Qt docs for `QDialog::open()`:

> Shows the dialog as a window modal dialog, returning immediately.

To make the file dialog non modal simply open it with `QDialog::show()`.