# How to implement back and next button in custom file browse dialog Qt C++

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5

I am inplementing custom Qt based file opening dialog, because native QFileDialog causing some blocking to my application. I am able to implement followings.

- Home Link
- Desktop Link
- Parent Link (Up Button)
- DoubleClick navigation to dir

But not find how to do

- Prev Link
- Next link

So how can I do it in Qt5 with C++ ?

Comment: Instead of rewriting your own dialog, did you try to pass `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog`to `QFileDialog` c'tor and call `show()`? That shouldn't block your application

Comment: What do you mean by "some blocking to my application" ? if it's related to window modality then you should have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24279382/how-to-make-qfiledialog-not-modal-in-qt5

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this as

```
struct BrowsingHistory
{
    QString dir;
    BrowsingHistory * next;
    BrowsingHistory * prev;
    BrowsingHistory(const QString & path = "") :
        dir(path),
        next(0),
        prev(0)
    {}
};

BrowsingHistory  *m_history;
BrowsingHistory  *m_historyHead;
```

In constructor I initialized as ..

```
m_history = m_historyHead = new BrowsingHistory(/*Your default location*/);
```

m_historyHead is used for memory deallocation in destructor, as it always point at start of list ( basically struct BrowsingHistory is LinkedList implimentation)

```
while(m_historyHead)
{
    BrowsingHistory * temp = m_historyHead;
    m_historyHead = m_historyHead->next;
    delete temp;
}
```

m_history : always point to current path.

on click of desktopButton, homeButton, parentButton, I invoked RegisterHistory() which defined as ...

```
void RegisterHistory(const QString& dirPath)
{
    if(m_history->dir != dirPath)
    {
        if(m_history->next)
        {
            m_history->next->dir = dirPath;
            m_history = m_history->next;
            BrowsingHistory * currentHistory = m_history->next;
            while(currentHistory)
            {
                BrowsingHistory * temp = currentHistory;
                currentHistory = currentHistory->next;
                delete temp;
            }
            m_history->next = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            BrowsingHistory * currentHistory = new BrowsingHistory(dirPath);
            currentHistory->prev = m_history;
            m_history->next = currentHistory;
            m_history = m_history->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Now here are next & prev slots:

```
void btnNext_Clicked()
{
    if(m_history && m_history->next)
    {
        QString dirPath = m_history->next->dir;
        ui->listFileView->setRootIndex(m_pDirModel->setRootPath(dirPath));
        m_history = m_history->next;
    }
}

void btnBack_Clicked()
{
    if(m_history && m_history->prev)
    {
        QString dirPath = m_history->prev->dir;
        ui->listFileView->setRootIndex(m_pDirModel->setRootPath(dirPath));
        m_history = m_history->prev;
    }
}
```